# PDO not found in laravel framework

Tags: laravel, pdo, shared-hosting

I'm using Laravel and I get this error after 2 months using this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/origomal/laravel/config/database.php:16
```

Any idea?

Pdo is turned on!

Answer (score 0):

May be try clearing config cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Without ssh access?